# How to convert object into array with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have below object

```
{
    "holdings": [
        {
            "label": "International",
            "value": 6
        },
        {
            "label": "Federal",
            "value": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Provincial",
            "value": 7
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to convert it into below object with lodash

```
{
    "holdings": [
        [
            "International",
            6
        ],
        [
            "Federal",
            4
        ],
        [
            "Provincial",
            7
        ],
        [
            "Corporate",
            7
        ]
    ]
}
```

is there any way to change it. Please suggest.

Comment: does it need to be with lodash?

Comment: yes...but suggest if you have any better solution

Comment: `holdings.map(function(l){return Object.keys(l).map(function(v){return l[v]})})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use only lodash, then you can do it with [`_.mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) and [`_.values`](https://lodash.com/docs#values) to get the result, like this

```
console.log(_.mapValues(data, _.partial(_.map, _, _.values)));
// { holdings: [ [ 'International', 6 ], [ 'Federal', 4 ], [ 'Provincial', 7 ] ] }
```

The same can be written without the partial function, like this

```
console.log(_.mapValues(data, function(currentArray) {
    return _.map(currentArray, _.values)
}));
// { holdings: [ [ 'International', 6 ], [ 'Federal', 4 ], [ 'Provincial', 7 ] ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works recursively (So has to be called on the `holdings` property if you want to keep that) and "understands" nested objects and nested arrays. (vanilla JS):

```js
var source = {
    "holdings": [
        {
            "label": "International",
            "value": 6
        },
        {
            "label": "Federal",
            "value": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Provincial",
            "value": 7
        }
    ]
}

function ObjToArray(obj) {
  var arr = obj instanceof Array;

  return (arr ? obj : Object.keys(obj)).map(function(i) {
    var val = arr ? i : obj[i];
    if(typeof val === 'object')
      return ObjToArray(val);
    else
      return val;
  });
}

alert(JSON.stringify(ObjToArray(source.holdings, ' ')));
```